# Using slds, td in a table has overflowing text area. I need it to wrap

Tags: visualforce, slds

```
<td class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-12">
 <apex:outputField label="Reason" value="{!rl.Reason__c}" styleClass="slds-output"/>
</td>
```

I have a text area field - Reason__c. it's 255 chars and doesn't wrap. I've tried all of the slds wrap options with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<td class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-12 td-fixed-width" >
    <div class="slds-cell-wrap">
        <apex:outputField label="Reason" value="{!rl.Reason__c}" styleClass="slds-output" />
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.td-fixed-width {
    width: 10rem;
}
```

You need put wrapped content in defined/fixed width to work

Comment: It worked! However, I didn't need to add the CSS. Thank you!

Comment: oh ya true. I am using it for resizable columns, so mentioned it. You can have a look at it: https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/06/23/custom-table-in-lwc/. Please mark answer as accepted as it worked. Thanks!